# How to retrieve RouteValues in ActionSelector in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/MarcusKohnert/MoreThanOneRouteHitActionSelector) to better understand the problem here. I have two actions on two different controllers bound to the same route.

```
http://localhost/sameControllerRoute/{identifier}/values

[Route("sameControllerRoute")]
public class FirstController : Controller
{
    public FirstController()
    {
        // different EF Core DataContext than SecondController and possibly other dependencies than SecondController
    }

    [HttpGet("{identifier}/values")]
    public IActionResult Values(string identifier, DateTime from, DateTime to) // other parameters than SecondController/Values
    {
        return this.Ok("Was in FirstController");
    }
}

[Route("sameControllerRoute")]
public class SecondController : Controller
{
    public SecondController()
    {
        // different EF Core DataContext than FirstController and possibly other dependencies than FirstController
    }

    [HttpGet("{identifier}/values")]
    public IActionResult Values(string identifier, int number, string somethingElse) // other parameters than FirstController/Values
    {
        return this.Ok("Was in SecondController");
    }
}
```

Since there are two matching routes, the default ActionSelector fails with:

> '[...] AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. [...]'
>   which is comprehensible.

So I thought I can implement my [own ActionSelector](https://github.com/MarcusKohnert/MoreThanOneRouteHitActionSelector/blob/master/CustomActionSelector/MoreThanOneRouteHitActionSelector.cs#L9). In there I would implement the logic that resolves the issue of multiple routes via same logic depending on the 'identifier' route value ([line 27](https://github.com/MarcusKohnert/MoreThanOneRouteHitActionSelector/blob/master/CustomActionSelector/MoreThanOneRouteHitActionSelector.cs#L27) in code)

If 'identifier' value is a --> then FirstController

If 'identifier' value is b --> then SecondController

and so on...

```
    protected override IReadOnlyList<ActionDescriptor> SelectBestActions(IReadOnlyList<ActionDescriptor> actions)
    {
        if (actions.HasLessThan(2)) return base.SelectBestActions(actions); // works like base implementation

        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            if (action.Parameters.Any(p => p.Name == "identifier"))
            {
                /*** get value of identifier from route (launchSettings this would result in 'someIdentifier') ***/

                // call logic that decides whether value of identifier matches the controller

                // if yes
                return new List<ActionDescriptor>(new[] { action }).AsReadOnly();

                // else 
                // keep going
            }
        }

        return base.SelectBestActions(actions); // fail in all other cases with AmbiguousActionException
    }
```

But I haven't found a good solution to get access to the route values in ActionSelector. Which is comprehensible as well because ModelBinding hasn't kicked in yet since MVC is still trying to figure out the Route.

A dirty solution could be to get hold of `IHttpContextAccessor` and regex somehow against the path.

But I'm still hoping you could provide a better idea to retrieve the route values even though ModelBinding hasn't happend yet in the request pipeline.

Comment: don't use only links, as they could be broken in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing the proposed [solution](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6413) by the ASP.NET team. This was to implement an IActionConstrain as shown here:

```
// Copyright (c) .NET Foundation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See License.txt in the project root for license information.

using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionConstraints;

namespace ActionConstraintSample.Web
{
    public class CountrySpecificAttribute : Attribute, IActionConstraint
    {
        private readonly string _countryCode;

        public CountrySpecificAttribute(string countryCode)
        {
            _countryCode = countryCode;
        }

        public int Order
        {
            get
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext context)
        {
            return string.Equals(
                context.RouteContext.RouteData.Values["country"].ToString(),
                _countryCode,
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.ActionConstraintSample.Web/CountrySpecificAttribute.cs

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you need to use ActionSelector at all for your scenario. Accordingly, to provided code, your controllers works with different types of resources (and so they expect different query parameters). As so, it is better to use different routing templates. Something like this for example:

- FirstController: `/sameControllerRoute/resourceA/{identifier}/values`
- SecondController: `/sameControllerRoute/resourceB/{identifier}/values`

---

In the scope of REST, when we are talking about `/sameControllerRoute/{identifier}/values` route template, we expect that different `identifier` means the same resource type, but different resource name. And so, as API consumers, we expect that all of the following requests are supported

```
/sameControllerRoute/a/values?from=20160101&to=20170202
/sameControllerRoute/b/values?from=20160101&to=20170202

/sameControllerRoute/a/values?number=1&somethingElse=someData
/sameControllerRoute/b/values?number=1&somethingElse=someData
```

That is not true in your case

Comment: Thanks for editing and replying. You have really good and valid points from an architecturally point of view.

The controller works with the same abstract type of resource but internally has different implementations. And thats the point of the whole project (internal enterprise application). Those different implementations are supposed to be hidden behind uniform endpoints.